# Adding Array and putting it in label

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to add all the scores(Array) that a person types in together. But everytime the button is pressed the scores are not added, but placed beside eachother in the label. This is my code:

```
function displayScores(e:MouseEvent):void

{
    lblOutput.text = "";
    lblOutcome.text = "";
    var i:int = 1
    for(var x=0; x < scores.length; x++)
    {
    lblOutput.text += "Hole " + i++ + ":  " + scores[x] + "\r";
    }
    lblOutcome.text += "Total: " + all(scores)
}


function all(scores):Number

{
    var total:Number = 0;
    for (var x:int=0; x<scores.length; x++)
    {

    total += scores[x];

    }

    return total 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like JavaScript, the ActionScript + operator can also be used to concatenate strings. I'm guessing that the values stored in your scores Array are strings, in which case you need to convert them to integers before attempting to tally up your score (see below). Alternatively, you could store them as integers in the array in the first place.

```
function all(scores):Number
{
    var total:Number = 0;
    for (var x:int=0; x<scores.length; x++)
    {
        total += parseInt(scores[x]);
    }

    return total 
}
```